# Parameterized rdlc report using reportviewer control in windows forms [ local rdlc report ]

Tags: winforms, reportviewer

I want to make local parameterized report using reportviewer control.

Can any body give hint?

I want to get following output

```
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Bill No : 101  Name : abc  Address : adsf  Phone:9889898  <------    Master Table
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Item No        Name        Price           Qty            Total <------     Detail Table 
-----------------------------------------------------------------------
1              abc         40              2              80
2              adsf        34              2              ??
-----------------------------------------------------------------
```

Grand Total : ?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using SQL Server then try using a stored procedure and submitting the parameters to it as usual, then bind your local report to the dataset that is returned. I dont know of a way in Winforms to have the parms show up dynaically like webforms. in winforms I ended uo constructed my own reporting submission sub system to handle this....

After you bind the datasetto the report you must perform the Refresh on the reportviewer object